# Conditional async calls with objective c

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous

I'm moving from sync calls to async calls and wonder what a good approach is to implement conditional async requests?

For example, i have the following method:

```
-(void)getSomeData:(NSInteger)data
{
    [Set data which will be used in the layout]

    if (data == 1)
    {
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [Set data which will be used in the layout]
            [Do Some layout calls]
        }
    }

    [Do Some layout calls]
}
```

It need to execute the [Do some layout calls] when fetching data async but also when the condition is not met.

I have a lot of methods like this and it seems like it creates a lot of 'duplicate' code or need a lot of method extraction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blocks to avoid code duplication.

```
- (void)getSomeData:(NSInteger)data
{
    void(^setData)(void) = ^(void) {
        [Set data which will be used in the layout]
    };

    void(^doLayoutJob)(void) = ^(void) {
        [Do Some layout calls]
    };


    setData();
    if (data == 1)
    {
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            setData();                 
            doLayoutJob();
        }
    }

    doLayoutJob();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get data in completion block, and then call function which will setup data and do some layouts. You can can call get data completion block according to your conditions.

```
- (void)setUp
{
    NSData *data = nil;
    [self setUpData:data];
    if (data)
    {
        [self getDataFromUrlString:@"URL" dataCompletion:^(id data) {
            [self setUpData:data];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)setUpData:(id)data
{
    [Set data which will be used in the layout];
    [Do Some layout calls]
}

- (void)getDataFromUrlString:(NSString *)urlString dataCompletion:(void(^)(id data))dataCompletion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            dataCompletion(data);
        });
    });
}
```